# Enable/Disable Popper.js tooltip if element exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to disable the popper.js tooptip if there is an element with a specific class on the page.

Let me explain ... I have a plugin that creates notifications dynamically, these notifications disappear every so often. I would like, that when a notification appears, the tooltip of popper.js will be disabled, and when the notification is closed, the tooltip will be enabled again.

This is what I have implemented so far, it works well, but I was wondering if there was another way a little more elegant.

```
    new Plugin({
        callbacks: {
            beforeShow: function() {
                $('.navbar-nav [title]').tooltip('disable');
            },
            afterClose: function () {
                if (!$('.notification').length) {
                    $('.navbar-nav [title]').tooltip('enable');
                }
            }
        }
    });
```